# How to render nextjs app into an existing web site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, rendering

I already have a website and I've build a small app in nextjs. now i want to render the app into the existing website.

How do I do that?

Comment: What's the techstack of that existing website, and what's your level of controlling it? I mean, using iframes is definitely most direct approach (which requires the minimum amount of modifications), but it has its drawbacks. In theory, one should be able to use web components for the same task - but the foundation should be ready.